# .NET Service to monitor web page changes

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I want to create a service that will monitor changes to web pages i.e. the page content has been updated. I am trying to think of the best way to achieve this and at present I am considering a couple of options. Note that there could be **hundreds** of pages to monitor and the interval for checking could be seconds or hours (configurable).

1. Create a windows service for each page to monitor
2. Create a windows service that spawns a thread for each page to monitor

Now, I am concerned which of these is the best approach and whether these is an alternative I haven't considered. I thought 1 would have the benefit of isolating each monitoring task but would come at the expense of overhead in terms of physical resources and effort to create/maintain. The second would be slightly more complex but cleaner. Obviously it would also lose isolation in that if the service fails then all monitoring will fail.

Comment: does each page have its own interval, or does the interval apply to all pages equally?

Comment: What is a "Web page" in this case? A file?

Comment: Web page would be an actual web page somewhere on the internet. Interval could be different for each.

Comment: So 1 web page equals one Uri? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar and I solved it by having a persisted queue (a SQL Server table) that would store the remote Uri along with the interval and a DateTime for the last time it ran.

I can then get all entries that I want to run by selecting the ones that has lastRun + interval < now.

If your smallest interval are in the region of seconds, you probably want to use a ThreadPool, so that you can issue several request at the same time. (Remember to adjust the maxConnections setting in your app.config accordingly).

I would use one Windows service (have a look at the TopShelf project for that) and I would then have Quartz.Net trigger the jobs. With Quartz, you can control whether it has to wait for previous jobs to finish etc.

Comment: I was thinking of a .NET service monitoring changes in sources through a windows service. I guess each 'check' could be instantiated through an enterprise scheduler. SSIS was then going to be used for ETL, as there would be other sources beyond web pages e.g. FTP, files, etc. So wanted to keep the process common.

Comment: Try to use events where they exists. For instance, the Filesystemwatcher can monitor source file changes and issue events. It can monitor the machine it is installed on or through network shares but not over HTTP/FTP etc. Setup monitoring agents on the remote machines that configure themselves from the master node so that you can handle the amount you are talking about.
And have a look at Rhino ETL instead of SSIS. It's a much more pleasant way to move data.

Comment: Most of the remote machines would not be under my control. So I will still need to implement some form of polling mechanism. We have experience with SSIS and that will therefore be their preference.

Comment: The other concern here is that if there was one windows service, how would it handle a thread for each source if there were hundreds of sources?

Comment: Since there's no way for you to listen on events for all sources, you have to fall back to some sort of polling mechanism, right? Given the polling scenario, you can use my suggested queuing approach and poll them in batches in parallel. That is when the threading come in. I don't see the benefit of keeping unused threads around just to isolate them from each other. When you are forced to poll for data, get the batch, do the job, persist result and return the thread.

Comment: So, a windows service will retrieve the tasks to perform from the sql table. Those that need to be executed will fire up from the thread pool. Each of these would start up a job in a scheduling tool such as Quartz.net? Or would each task retrieve the data (if the data had changed)? How about just having each task in the scheduling tool and not have a windows service at all?

Comment: If you have each of them in a scheduler, you are looking at a lot of management for that. And they would have to wait for each other as there might be enough threads for all of them to execute in parallel if that should happen. That's how Quartz work normally, jobs wait.
I would have one job in Quartz that would start a process that handles a batch of tasks. Then I would fire up a work item for each task and that could happen in parallel. 
If you need to add a level of parallelism, you could perhaps run several instances of the job. Make sure you have a mechanism to mark items in progress.

Comment: The thinking behind each task being separate is to keep them isolated from each other. If something fails then only one will be affected and it is obvious for support teams to investigate.

Comment: Introduce exception handling, timeout handling and monitoring as you see fit. Having hundreds of instances of the same service just isn't a solution IMHO.

Comment: Surely common exception handling, monitoring and other NFRs would/could be provided by the scheduling tool and ETL tasks? And every task will be different, although many will indeed be similar. Don't get me wrong, I like reuse but in this instance I think it could be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Creating one Windows Service is the way to go... regarding the failure of this windows Service there are several measures you could take to deal with that - for example configure windows to automatically restart the Windows Service on failure...

I would recommend using a thread pool approach and/or a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) in combination with a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) or [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) .