# Smart detection of html content changes

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm looking for algorithm/library (preferably in c#) that can detect changes in the content of an html page intelligently.

For example if the page was techcrunch.com, it would only match when there's a new post or significant changes to the page. it would ignore html comments, javascript, minor updates such as the number of comments, etc...

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: It seems that you need to design your algorithm

Comment: I'm looking for something generic that will work on all websites.

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. My suggestion is to google it. This type of question really isn't a good fit for StackOverflow, but if you do find some code out there and get stuck while trying to demo it, definitely come back and see us and post a programming question. We're happy to help. Good luck :)

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553898/net-service-to-monitor-web-page-changes .. however I am not sure if you can build something generic unless you know of the structure of the web page in advance and that structure remains the same ..

Comment: what if the algorithm looks at the percentage changed. ex: the new html is 10% different than the previous html, result:something has changed.

Comment: Removed the tag [tag:data-mining], as there is no data mining in this question. Comparing web pages is not data mining.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to count how many elements are on the page, or specific portion of the page. There are thousands of ways one could implement JS to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

For my assumption, that, you request the page with your C# program.

Actually, there are hundreds of ways to do it.

I'll give you one:

Number one, the easiest and dummy algorithm.. is

```
while(true) {
    checkModifyDate();

    if(date is newer) {
        do anything you want...
    }
    do it again in next 10 mins()
}
```

That checkModifyDate() function will **"ONLY"** check the HTTP Header for changes.
Then you can do anything later.

You can add it to a timer object that runs every xxx minute or to a thread and set it to automatically do the job for you.

Hope this helps.